# FLASH_MODE_AUTO not working in Android on Samsung Note III

Tags: android, camera, camera-flash

android : FLASH_MODE_AUTO not working for camera on Samsung note III Android 4.4.2

I have added permission AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

I am using following code to set the camera parameters

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
if (flashModes.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO))
{
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
}
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Whenever i click capture it does not show flash on Note III. However, On Samsung Grand , Grand II and Google Nexus and  HTC Sensation it is working properly

Note :If I use FLASH_MODE_TORCH then it works properly but it shows flash always.

Please help me if anybody has faced similar issue.

Comment: Hi. Not much time after the question... do you remember if you ever got it to work? 